# Can I use same flutter app for both android and ios apps?

Tags: android, swift, flutter, dart, mobile

Let's say I have an app that is both native android and ios.
If I want to change one of the features using flutter, can I write with flutter only once for both android and ios?

The current method: **add-to-app**, I think only works for one app, either ios or android.

Comment: You need to create the new module in Flutter/Dart, and then load it inside your iOS and Android code. But the code in Flutter/Dart (the new module) remains the same for both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, if you know dart language you can use it to write your application in Flutter. According to your use case, you want to run the application on Android & ios. Use those packages that are available for both Android & IOS.

More details - https://flutter.dev/multi-platform

You can also use the same source code to generate mobile, web and desktop builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dart language with flutter , it will be uses both Operating system (Android & IOS). make sure app code will be written with dart language